# How does PORTLET_APPLICATION table get populated

Tags: jetspeed2

How does the PORTLET_APPLICATION table get populated in jetspeed ?

One of my web apps is not deploying and this app does not contain a corresponding entry in the jetspeed table PORTLET_APPLICATION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entry PORTLET_APPLICATION table it means that your application is not registered with jetspeed. JetspeedContainerServlet is responsible for sending signal to jetspeed to deploy your application. Please put you application war in 'jetspeed/WEB-INF/deploy' folder.

After this jetspeed deploy service will add container servlet and move it webapps folder.